# Run a scheduled task only once based on an event

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a task that I want to run just once each time the system memory reaches less than 10 %.
[Scheduled Task Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmXI0.jpg)

Would this run until the memory is less than 10% or will it run just once? If it runs until less than 10%, how do I get it to just run once?

The task I am running is a PowerShell script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the task you're running is a script, you can add a line setting the Task itself to disabled as the script completes:

`move "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\TEST TASK.job" "C:\WINDOWS\Tasks\TEST TASK.bak`"

*From here: https://serverfault.com/questions/164097/is-it-possible-to-disable-a-scheduled-task-from-the-command-line-in-windows-xp*

Or you could write a checkfile at the end of the task, and check for its existence at the beginning of the task:

```
if exist complete.file goto :eof
```

PowerShell makes this even easier:

```
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "TaskName"
```

*From here: https://serverfault.com/questions/912486/enable-and-disable-scheduled-task-with-powershell-and-variable*

Comment: Ok. So if I needed the task again later on, I would just disable and enable the task in the powershell script?

Comment: Your question does not specify the means by which you want the task to be re-enabled. If you disabled it via PS (that's the better way, anyway), you'd be able to enable it using either PS or the Task Scheduler UI. Disabling it by renaming means you'd have to rename it back to filename.task, and to reverse the checkfile method you'd just delete the checkfile.